# Oracle SQL dividing two self defined columns

Tags: sql, oracle

if i have the following select two count cases:

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END) as completed_callbacks,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) as completed_within_2hours
```

and i want to devide the two results with eachother how can i achieve this?

this is my attemt however that failed:

```
 CASE(completed_callbacks / completed_within_2hours * 100) as Percentage
```

i know this is a rather simple question but i havnt been able to find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a derived table:

```
SELECT completed_callbacks / completed_within_2hours * 100
FROM   (SELECT Count(CASE
                       WHEN status = 'Færdig' THEN 1
                     END) AS completed_callbacks,
               Count(CASE
                       WHEN solved_seconds / 60 / 60 <= 2 THEN 1
                     END) AS completed_within_2hours
        FROM   yourtable
        WHERE  ...)
```

Comment: It's actually called a "derived table", not a sub-query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have a question, where do i push  the "WHERE SOMETHING = 0" and how can i select other rows aswell?

Comment: You have to put the `WHERE` in the derived table in order to count only the rows that you need. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "can i select other rows aswell", but in short, you can select about everything you want by using functionalities as `GROUP BY`, `UNION`, or `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with x as (
  select 'Y' as completed, 'Y' as completed_fast from dual
  union all
  select 'Y' as completed, 'N' as completed_fast from dual
  union all
  select 'Y' as completed, 'Y' as completed_fast from dual
  union all
  select 'N' as completed, 'N' as completed_fast from dual
)
select 
sum(case when completed='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as count_completed,
sum(case when completed='N' then 1 else 0 end) as count_not_completed,
sum(case when completed='Y' and completed_fast='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as count_completed_fast,
case when (sum(case when completed='Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 0) then 0 else
  ((sum(case when completed='Y' and completed_fast='Y' then 1 else 0 end) / sum(case when completed='Y' then 1 else 0 end))*100)
end pct_completed_fast
from x;
```

Results:

```
"COUNT_COMPLETED"   "COUNT_NOT_COMPLETED"   "COUNT_COMPLETED_FAST"  "PCT_COMPLETED_FAST"
3   1   2   66.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
```

The trick is to use SUM rather than COUNT, along with a decode or CASE.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='Færdig' THEN 1 END) 
  /
   COUNT(CASE WHEN SOLVED_SECONDS /60 /60 <= 2 THEN 1 END) 
  * 100 
  as 
   Percentage
```